# Memory issue with ntoskrnl but no issues detected with memorytest

Tags: memory, windows-11

My machine is often off in the mornings, despite being left on over night

I am trying to find out why. When I turn on the machine, I head over to event viewer and I see

[image]

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.

I use `BlueScreenView` and I see

[image]

A google of this shows RAM is often the cause. This PC has been fine for over a year, and the issue only started 8 days ago... I accept that maybe the RAM has become faulty.

So, from research, it is suggested to run a [MemTest](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ntoskrnlexe-causing-crashes-and-bsod-even-in-safe/73055535-78e0-417e-9b64-d9c91bc7997b?auth=1)

I did and sadly, the results were no error

[image]

What else can I do?

Comment: Could be mechanical or thermal related, dust or a poor connection can make errors occur when everything else seems fine. Remove the sticks, clean the slots and memory stick contacts and refit. Otherwise does the temperature go up or down significantly where this machine is overnight?

Comment: I will try that. The machine is in UK so weather isn't that varied at the moment (in regards to heat). Thanks